# How to return different POJO using Java generics

Tags: java, generics, pojo

I would like a method to return a different type of List.

I tried something like the following but not sure if this approach is correct or not. How can I do this?

```
public <T> List<T>  getPageDetails(Long adId,String source);
```

Based on the `source` I will return a different List of objects in the implementation method.

Like in implementation if the source is 1, then will have to return List of objects type1, if the source is 2 then list of objects type2, etc.

Comment: plaese elaborate more.

Comment: Don't you want to return a list?  So surely `public <T> List<T> getPageDetails(Long adId, String source);` would make more sense?

Answer (score 1):

```
private Object objT;

public <T> List<T> magicalListGetter(Class<T> cls) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(cls.cast(actuallyT));
    try {
        list.add(cls.getConstructor().newInstance()); // If default constructor
    } ...
    return list;
}
```

One can give a generic type parameter to a method too. You have correctly deduced that one needs the correct class instance, to create things (cls.getConstructor().newInstance()).

Without class :

```
public <T> List<T> magicalListGetter() {
return new ArrayList<T>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please help me to use this without class? and is it possible?also i will return only one type of objects at a time based on the source provided.

Comment: Thank you very much, up voted but will try this approach and update here

Answer (score 1):

You can use genrics to return multiple list

```
   public <T> List<T>  getPageDetails(Long adId,String source);

public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution sol = new Solution();

        List<String> list = sol.getPageDetails(String.class, 0l, "source");
    }

    public <T> List<T> getPageDetails(Class<T> c, Long adId, String source) {
        List<T> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Object> objectList = getObjectList(adId, source);
        for (Object o : objectList) {
            T t = c.cast(o);
            list.add(t);
        }
        return list;

    }

    private List<Object> getObjectList(Long adId, String source) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, could you please how to implement and return a different list?

Comment: Thank you very much, up voted but will try this approach and update here